# Проблема с преобразованием в LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, localdate

Есть метод в котором возникает ошибка , при использовании форматера в последней строке где return . В чем причина ?

```
public LocalDateTime removeCharT(LocalDateTime value) {
    String temp  = value.toString();
    LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.parse(temp, formatter);
    return LocalDateTime.parse(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss").
            format(time));
}

private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
```

```
time = 2021-03-12T14:23
formatter - Value(YearOfEra,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD)''Value(MonthOfYear,2)''Value(DayOfMonth,2)'T'Value(HourOfDay,2)':'Value(MinuteOfHour,2)
```

пишет в консоли - Text '2021-03-12  14:23:00' could not be parsed at index 10

Comment: В паттерне два пробела между датой и временем, в дате один

Comment: пробовал уже не работает все равно

Comment: А вообще, в чем смысл преобразовывать в строку, потом парсить, потом форматировать, и потом опять парсить? Что вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: хочу избавится от символа T посередине  2021-03-12T14:23

Comment: Тогда вам нужно возвращать форматированный String вместо LocalDateTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Символ T есть только в текстовом представлении. В самом объекте `LocalDateTime` его нет, он появляется только при преобразовании в текст. Множественное преобразование в строку потом обратно, и так много раз, не имеет никакого смысла - все равно при переводе `LocalDateTime` в строку через `toString()` будет появляться эта буква T.

Если нужно вывести без T, то нужно форматировать в строку с помощью форматтера, в котором нет буквы T между датой и временем.

```
public String format(LocalDateTime value) {
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

так попробуйте))

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class tt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
          System.out.format("%tm-%te-%tY %tl:%tM", c, c, c, c, c);              
 // -->  "03-31-2021 8:46"
    }

}

/*%tB Преобразование даты и времени - полное название месяца, зависящее от локали.
%td, %te Преобразование даты и времени - 2-значный день месяца. td имеет ведущие нули по мере необходимости, te - нет.
%ty, %tY Преобразование даты и времени - ty = год из 2 цифр, tY = год из 4 цифр.
%tl Преобразование даты и времени - час в 12-часовой формат.
%tM Преобразование даты и времени - минуты в 2-значном формате с ведущими нулями по мере необходимости.
%tp Преобразование даты и времени - время до и после полудня в зависимости от региона (нижний регистр).
%tm Преобразование даты и времени - месяцы в 2-значном формате, при необходимости с нулями в начале.
%tD Преобразование даты и времени - дата как% tm% td% ty
*/
```